# What is the complexity of comparing 2 ordered sets in c++ by using inbuilt (==) operator.(Assuming set size=n))

Tags: c++14

Can someone tell me stl implementation of (==) operator in set.Let say if i have 2 sets s1 and s2.And if i want to compare if(s1==s2) then is it constant time of linear time.

Comment: [This `std::set` comparison reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp) might be helpful.

Comment: Well it certainly can't be constant time.

Comment: I was thinking, if sets have different size then complexity can be constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [operator ==](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp) for `std::set` #1:

> ```
> template< class Key, class Compare, class Alloc >
> bool operator==( const std::set<Key,Compare,Alloc>& lhs,
>              const std::set<Key,Compare,Alloc>& rhs );
> ```

which is accompagnied by the following explanation:

> Compares the contents of two containers.
>   1-2) Checks if the contents of lhs and rhs are equal, that is, they have the same number of elements and each element in lhs compares equal with the element in rhs at the same position.

That should answer the first part of your question. And with respect to time complexity, further down we have:

> **Complexity**
>   1-2) Constant if lhs and rhs are of different size, otherwise linear in the size of the container